# Basic aiosmtpd SMTP server example

Tags: python, aiosmtpd

How do I convert the following basic SMTP server that uses `smtpd` to one that uses `aiosmtpd` instead?

```
import smtpd

class CustomSMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        myqueue.queue.put(data)

self.server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 10025), None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To translate your CustomSMTPServer into something that uses aiosmtpd, you have to define a handler class with a `handle_DATA()` method that does the same thing as your `process_message()` method:

```
import aiosmtpd.controller

class CustomSMTPHandler:
    async def handle_DATA(self, server, session, envelope):
        myqueue.queue.put(envelope.content)
        return '250 OK'

handler = CustomSMTPHandler()
self.server = aiosmtpd.controller.Controller(handler)
self.server.start()
input("Server started. Press Return to quit.")
self.server.stop()
```

Note that `handle_DATA()` returns "250 OK" which tells the SMTP client that the message was received and handled successfully. Unlike smtpd, with aiosmtpd you are required to return an SMTP response code in `handle_DATA()`.

Note that `handle_DATA()` must be a coroutine function, that is, defined using `async def`. If you need compatibility with Python 3.4, use an `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator on `handle_DATA()` instead.

Also note that `self.server.start()` runs the SMTP server in a separate thread, unlike `asyncore.loop()` which takes over the current thread.

If you need access to `peer`, `mailfrom` or `rcpttos`, they are available as `session.peer`, `envelope.mail_from` and `envelope.rcpt_tos`, respectively.

Comment: Getting this error now: `RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: '2'`

Comment: @opsdisk Sorry, I forgot that handle_DATA must be a coroutine (async def). I've edited my solution -- it should work now.

Comment: that did the trick...just found the github ticket for better documentation for this type of example